# How can I read YUV in opencv with python?

Tags: python, opencv

I read picture using "cv.imread"

What I wanted to do was "comparing from 'convert to yuv from rgb with fomula' to 'convert to yuv from rgb using cv.cvtColor(img, cv.COLOR_BGR2YUV)'

and this is my code

```
img = cv.imread('pic.jpeg')

# convert to yuv using fomula
toYUV = np.zeros((len(img), len(img[0]), 3), np.uint8)
for i in range(len(img)):
    for j in range(len(img[0])):
        y = 0.257*img[i][j][0] + 0.504*img[i][j][1]+0.095*img[i][j][2]+16
        u = -0.148*img[i][j][0] - 0.291*img[i][j][1]+0.499*img[i][j][2]+128
        v = 0.439*img[i][j][0] - 0.368*img[i][j][1]-0.071*img[i][j][2]+128
        toYUV[i][j] = [y, u, v]
cv.imshow('toYUV', toYUV)

# convert to yuv using cvtColor
yuv = cv.cvtColor(img, cv.COLOR_BGR2YUV)

cv.imshow('yuv', yuv)
```

as you see, I saved converted value using fomula, but the result was not that I expected.

I think I saved YUV format data to toYUV, but cv.imshow read it just like RGB format
How I read my "toYUV" that contains YUV data?

Comment: What your data types. `toYUV` is an `uint8` array, but your operations use and produce `float`s.

Answer (score 1):

If you use **PIL/Pillow**, **ImageMagick** or **wand**, they have an image *"container"* that keeps track of the type of your image and any metadata, such as EXIF or IPTC and ICC colour profiles. So, if you open an image with **PIL** and convert it to HSV colourspace, **PIL** knows and remembers that your pixel values now represent Hue, Saturation and Value rather than RGB.

**OpenCV** doesn't do that - it is more interested in hard-core, high performance computer vision (hence the name) than cataloguing, indexing and managing photo archives. It stores your pixels in a very simple Numpy array and other than the dimensions of the array, has no understanding or interest in what the pixels mean - it generally assumes they are BGR when saving and displaying them - or maybe greyscale or BGRA if there are 1 or 4 channels.

---

Coming back closer to your question, I think you'll find it easier to treat your YUV image as three independent greyscale images if you want to compare them. So you could use `Y,U,V = cv2.split(YOURIMAGE)` to split your Y, U and V channels into 3 separate, single-channel images, then use `rowOfThree = np.hstack((Y,U,V))` to put the three grey channels side-by-side in a row for display.